# python sqlalchemy union query，'Query' object has no attribute 'spends'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, union

```
#app adset
app_list = db.session.query(
    AdsetAppReport.adset_id.label("adset_id"),
    func.sum(AdsetAppReport.spend).label("spends"),
    ).group_by(AdsetAppReport.adset_id)

#web adset
web_list = db.session.query(
    AdsetReport.adset_id.label("adset_id"),
    func.sum(AdsetReport.spend).label("spends"),
    ).group_by(AdsetReport.adset_id)

#union two tables
both_list = app_list.union(web_list)

#Query
adset_list = db.session.query(
    Adset.adset_id,
    Adset.user_os,
    both_list.spends,
    ).filter(both_list.adset_id == Adset.adset_id) \
     .all()
```

I want to merge two table as both_list, then make the adset inner join in the temporary table.
when i run the code, but it show me AttributeError.
AttributeError: both_list 'Query' object has no attribute 'spends'

Comment: What is the structure of your tables? Reducing the query would definitely help. Moreover, `app_list` and `web_list` are identical.

Comment: app_list is the table AdsetAppReport, web_list is the table AdsetReport,      they are not identical,two table's structure is similarity.I have reducing the query, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not check if this works, but creating a subquery might solve it. Moreover, I made the join explicit.

```
#union two tables
both_list = app_list.union(web_list).subquery()

#Query
adset_list = db.session.query(
        Adset.adset_id,
        Adset.user_os,
        both_list.c.spends,
    ).\
    join(both_list, both_list.c.adset_id == Adset.adset_id).\
    all()
```

Comment: thanks for your help in advance, but i receive the following error:'Alias' object has no attribute 'spends'

Comment: did you include the `c` in `both_list.c.spends` and `both_list.c.adset_id`? (Which stands for columns)